# Install Google Tag Manager (gtm) to Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome, google-tag-manager

I tried to install **GTM** to an **Angular** app by adding the *script* to the *head* and the *iframe* to the *body* in the *index.html* file.

I load the app in Chrome an I can see that are added in the html.

The **Google Tag Assistant** plugin from Chrome detects it well but when I go to the Network tab I can't see any *gtm.js* request and also I type in the console **google_tag_manager** and I get `google_tag_manager is not defined`.

I tried the plugin **angular-google-tag-manager** but happens the same.

I don't know what's going on, any guess?

Comment: follow this guide, it's by an Angular team member, it's the best: https://fluin.io/blog/google-analytics-with-tag-manager-and-angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was going on.

I had an *script* for the *cookies* of my app and I guess is using *gtm* or *analytics* and **commenting** that *script* solved the problem. I also tried changing **the order** of the *scripts* and also solved the problem, first *my gtm script* and after *the cookies script* which was causing the problem.